# css vertical alignment, weird result

Tags: css

I've created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zkLav/ showing the code in action. what's happening is the images and text alignment are step stacking and not aligning vertically. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

**CSS** markup:

```
.outList {
    display:table;
}
.outList span {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:10%;
}
.outList h4 {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:50%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.outList p {
    float:right;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    /*width:30%;*/
    text-align:right;
}
.outList img {
    width:100%;
}
```

**HTML** markup:

```
<ul>
    <li data-theme="c">
    <a href="detail.html">
        <div class="outList">
            <span><img src="simgs/listview_chk.png" /></span>
            <h4>Warmup</h4>
            <p>5 Minutes</p>
        </div>                             
    </a>                  
    </li> 

    <li data-theme="c">
    <a href="detail.html">
        <div class="outList">
            <span><img src="simgs/listview_chk.png" /></span>
            <h4>Machine Press</h4>
            <p>3 sets of</p>
        </div>                             
    </a>                  
    </li>

    <li data-theme="c">
    <a href="detail.html">
        <div class="outList">
            <span><img src="simgs/listview_chk.png" /></span>
            <h4>Lateral Pulldowns</h4>
            <p>3 sets of</p>
        </div>                             
    </a>                  
    </li>
</ul>​
​
```

A proper image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Your jsFiddle need some work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, take a look at [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/zkLav/1/)

Just remove the width in the next .css class:

```
.outList img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**UPDATE**

For the text at the right to be fully align, remove the `float:right;` from the `p` class:

```
.outList p {
    float:right;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    /*width:30%;*/
    text-align:right;
}
```

[Check this new update](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/zkLav/3/)

Comment: thanks the text on the end is not vertically aligning. You can see it in the jsfiddle as well. Any idea on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the divs, you don't need them given that you have the li's.

Also, why span the img? Get rid of that too.

---

When you did that, put the ul as the table, the li's as the rows and then the stuff in the a as the columns.